# Where to save the locaction of a config file?

Tags: configuration-files

I want the user in my program to specify the config folder when starting the program for the first time. Where do programs (on linux) normally store the path to their config folder, so that they find it every time they start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally programs store global configuration data (which apply for all users) somewhere in /etc  or in /usr/local/etc (e.g. in a subdirectory, or as a file with a relevant name).

User-specific configuration is usually stored in the user's home directory, either in a hidden file or in files within a hidden directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard.  It's entirely up to the application.  You will find them in /etc, /usr/local/etc, /usr/share/etc and even in the local directory.